# Debugging - Finding where Error statement in log is coming from

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am getting this error:

```
2015-01-29 13:49:36.520[5485:1610317] Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)
2015-01-29 13:49:36.523[5485:1610315] runEventually command failed. Error:Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 101.)" UserInfo=0x190a13a0 {code=101, error=object not found for update}
```

I don't know where it's coming from, and I'm looking for an easy way to track it's origin.

---

EDIT

Sorry I wasn't clearer. I realize this is something to do with Parse and saving the object. I was interested in learning more about how to debug this error in general.

All I have is an error log statement. I have exception breakpoints set in my project, but this error isn't throwing an exception, so the compiler doesn't break here.

What I'd like to know is, is there some kind of Symbolic Breakpoint, or any other kind of breakpoint, or even another debugging mechanism I could use to find the source of this logged Error Code if I had no idea how to proceed otherwise?

This isn't hypothetical - I actually have no idea which save is causing this error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing when you save, but you could have your save method throw an error with try and catch block if no object is found for an update. In debug mode, it will act as a breakpoint whenever an throw is reached

Comment: This previous answer is what I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423431/how-to-find-source-of-print-or-nslog-console-output-in-xcode I just added a symbolic breakpoint for `NSLog`.